# Ajax action link and css id

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This `ajax` link works correctly but when this part `" new { @class = "delete" } "` added didn't call the `DEL_row()` after success. If i remove this  `new { @class = "delete" }`
then `DEL_row()` will be called .

Code is as below:

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(" ",
                 "DeleteConfirmed",
                   new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", item.chanID } },
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {

                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                     HttpMethod = "GET",
                     OnSuccess = "DEl_row('" + item.chanID + "')"
                 }, new { @class = "delete" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the [overload with the signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470546%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
AjaxExtensions.ActionLink Method (AjaxHelper, String, String, Object, AjaxOptions, Object)
```

So your `RouteValueDictionary` parameter is interpreted incorrectly so you need to use an anonymous object instead:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ",
    "DeleteConfirmed",
    new { id = item.chanID },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
         HttpMethod = "GET",
         OnSuccess = "DEl_row('" + item.chanID + "')"
    }, new { @class = "delete" })
```

Or use a [different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493123%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which takes a `RouteValueDictionary` and the html attributes as a `IDictionary<string, Object>`

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ",
    "DeleteConfirmed",
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", item.chanID } },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
         HttpMethod = "GET",
         OnSuccess = "DEl_row('" + item.chanID + "')"
    }, new Dictionary<string, Object>{ { "class", "delete"} })
```